# ASP.Net MVC 4 Application in IIS Sub Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I've deployed my ASP.Net MVC 4 Application to a IIS sub directory ("sub" application under the root application):

root application: portal.tld
"sub" application: portal.tld/integration

The sub application is working, but all URLs refer to the root application.
How can that be? I rendered all URLs via Razor's

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home")
```

RouteConfig is default.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            namespaces: new string[] { "XYZ.XYZ.Controllers" },
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thomas, did you figure anything out for this? I am looking at something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately not... I ended up setting a different/separate application root. :-/